# Can we ignore $x^n$ against $e^x$ for any value of $n$ when $x$ is approaching to infinity.

Tags: limits

someone told me that as $x$ approach to infinity value of $e^x$ is increasing towards infinity rapidly more than what $x^n$. so we can neglect $x^n$ in comparison to $e^x$ when both are in summation form like: $x^n + e^x +7 \approx e^x$

Comment: What someone told you is true, although it was a imprecise statement. Was this your question or what is your question?

Comment: Yes, $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^ne^{-x}=0$ (indeed, $\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}dx=n!$), so $x^n\in o(e^x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since by Taylor series of exponential function is
$$\ e^x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
Therefore $$ e^x > \frac{x^{n +1}}{(n+1)!}.$$
$$ \frac{x^n}{e^x} < \frac{(n+1)!}{x}. $$
Taking limits as $x\to\infty$,
$$ \lim \frac{(n+1)!}{x} = 0 = \lim \frac{x^n}{e^x}$$
So yes we can

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).